# Does this functionality exist in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

In the following picture I have a total time taken to fix an issue by Cell B2 and C2 being filled in.  They post a time stamp when they are changed.  Cell M2 is the total time between the two actions.[image: Layer Issue Log]

In the next picture I have a Macro that adds a new row every time the button is pressed.  For this question I only need to use Columns A,B,C,J.  A&B are just the time stamp of when the marco was ran.  Column C is the new "layer total" so that value will increase to the nearest multiple of 20 (B7).  Column J is the average time per layer between the last two rows.  Example is that it takes 1.5 min(J20) per layer between layers 201(C20) and 185(C19).  [image: Macro Ran sheet]

My question is (after all this time) if there is a way to use the LOOKUP function to find all the pause times in Picture 1 between two layer values from Picture 2.  Example:  Find all the pause times between layers 140 and 162.  Then add those up pauses up into a single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at SUMIFS.

Example:

```
=SUMIFS(PausesSheet!M4:M100,PausesSheet!C4:C100,">=140",PausesSheet!C4:C100,"<=162")
```

The ">=140" and "<=162" (from your example) can be replaced with formula, e.g. `">=" & C8, ... "<=" & C9` , which you can use all the way down on your second worksheet.

Comment: I will give this a try.  It is much more simple looking than what I was thinking I would have to do.

Comment: Sorry it has been a couple of weeks, but this method worked perfectly.  It was just a matter of typing it in and editing it to fit my exact needs.  Thank you